# Sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n+n)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence defined by

$$a_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n+n)^2}$$

**I know that $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ $(a_n)= 0$.**

But when I tried another method I got an entirely different result!

What I had tried is:

$$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$$

on taking summation on both sides we get

$$\sum (a_{n+1}-a_{n})=\sum\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\\
\implies a_{n+1}-a_1\to\frac{\pi^2}{8}-1 \\
\implies a_{n+1}\to\frac{\pi^2}{8}-3/4  $$

So What I get is  $ a_{n+1}\to\frac{\pi^2}{8}-3/4$ as $n\to\infty$.

Is this true?

Comment: 1-1/4 become 3/4

Comment: That's odd: for $a_{n+1}-a_n$ I get
$$\frac1{(2n+1)^2}+\frac1{(2n+2)^2}-\frac1{(n+1)^2}
=\frac1{(2n+1)^2}-\frac3{4(n+1)^2}.$$

Comment: Incidentally, using a Riemann sum argument you can show $a_n \sim \frac{1}{2n}$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get:

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} -\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$

Then $$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_{n+1}-a_n)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}-\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=\left(\frac{\pi^2}{8}-1\right)-\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}$$

Since $a_1=\frac{1}{4},$ this means $a_{n+1}\to 0.$

It is much easier to prove it directly:

$$0\leq a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}< \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}$$